# Рассинхронизация содержимого файла, при правке по сети (Samba)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, samba

Имеем сервер W2k8r2x64(hostname:MLG7), на котором поднята текущая Ubuntu 16.04x64(hostname:PDV) в HyperV.
На PDV настроена раздача /opt через Samba

```
[opt]
    comment = Public Share
    path = /opt
    read only = No
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask = 0700
    directory mode = 0700
    guest ok = Yes
```

C клиента Windows7x64(hostname:B560) правлю в Eclipse Neon файл \\PDV\opt\target.mk и сохраняюсь. Затем проверяю alexey@pdv:/opt$ cat target.mk
и вижу, что в файле нет правок. А иногда все нормально, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Может ntpdate давно нормально не отрабатывал?

Comment: https://bogner.sh/2014/10/how-to-disable-smb-client-side-caching/